# Error during plperl compilation: quoted execution trapped by operation mask

Tags: postgresql, perl

When I try to create a perl function, I get an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS text AS $BODY$
  use v5.28;
  use warnings;
  my $output = `/data/myapp`; # or qx('/data/myapp')
  return $output;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plperl;
```

But I get this error while compiling this function:

```
'quoted execution (``,qx)' trapped by operation mask at line 5.
```

Am I using wrong syntax or is it a different issue?

Comment: In order to save this question I've reduced the typo and the complexity a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `plperlu` with a `u` at the end.

You do not get this error with the untrusted `plperlu`. It's only with `plperl`,

```
ERROR:  'quoted execution (``, qx)' trapped by operation mask at line 5.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "scriptdecrypt"
```

This op is blacklisted with `plperl` which only allows trusted code. Though I would be careful, because `plperl` like `plperlu` is insecure, just to a lesser degree. ;)